# Log4j2 causing PreferIP6 to fail

Tags: java, logging, java-8, log4j2, system-properties

If I run the following code

```
public class NetworkTester {
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.setProperty( "java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true" );
    System.setProperty( "java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "false" );
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName( "www.google.com" );
        System.out.println( addr );
            if ( addr instanceof Inet4Address ) {
                System.out.println( 4 );
            }
            if ( addr instanceof Inet6Address ) {
                System.out.println( 6 );
            }
    } catch ( UnknownHostException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

I get the following output

```
www.google.com/2607:f8b0:4009:801:0:0:0:2004
6
```

however if i add the line

```
private static Logger log4j = LogManager.getLogger();
```

and i import the following

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

I get

```
www.google.com/4.59.40.94
4
```

I am using log4j2 2.6.2 and jdk1.8.0_51. If i use `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true` as a vm argument i do get a IPv6 address. But the application I'm developing is meant to be run as an executable jar file and i cannot find a way to get the executable jar to run the vm argument without writing a bat file or script of some kind. 
How can i get My application to prefer ipv6 and run log4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a static initializer block  to the main class that sets the property before the static Logger field is initialized?

```
static {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");
}
```

Comment: Good idea, I should have thought about it!

Comment: This worked! Andy idea why the System property needs to be set before initializing log4j ?

Comment: My guess is that log4j looks up the local host name during initialization and this in turn uses ip v4 unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to avoid declaring your Log4j Logger in the class that contains your `main()`? If you declare a static Logger as an attribute of this main class, Log4j will be initialized before your first `main()` instruction.

Yet, I would be curious to understand how Log4j prevents you from using IPv6.

**Note**: if you want to set `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` when starting your app in command line using `java -jar`, you can do so using:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true -jar myapp.jar
```

(it didn't work on your side maybe because you have put `-D` after `-jar`?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using the -D at command line arg works but as i said the application is meant to be a runnable JAR file, thus i cant use command line arguments unless I make a .bat file. Additionally we want to log the parameters and errors both before and after we make a network connection. That network connection must be an IPv6 connection and the moment i declare a Log4j logger the app only uses IPv4.